# MySQL/PHP update query not executing

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tested the variables in the update statement and checked if a database connection is established, however the query doesn't run, can you please show me the error in my code.

```
for($i=0; $i <= $numcourses; $i++){
    echo '<div class="new'.$i.'" id="new'.$i.'"><label>'.$course_names[$i].'</label>
    <input name="edit'.$i.'" type="submit" value="Edit" /><input name="delete'.$i.'" type="submit" value="Delete" /><br /></div>';
    $name="edit".$i;    
    if (isset($_POST[$name])){
        echo '<input name="text" type="text" value="'.$course_names[$i].'" /><input name="save'.$i.'" type="submit" value="Save"/>';
    }   
    $name2="save".$i;
    if (isset($_POST[$name2])){
        include "includes/open.php";
            $newname=($_POST['text']);
            $int=$i+1;
            $query = "UPDATE course SET cname = '".$newname."' WHERE cid = '".$int."'";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            include "includes/close.php";
    }
}
```

Update: Thanx Marc B, adding `or die(mysql_error());`showed me the error in my code, everything works again and I'm back on track.

Comment: Have you tried just running the query in the database (sans PHP)? What error message do you get...?

Comment: If you need any more info to help me solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: That's why I asked for the error message...

Comment: Ok... so you are trying to update a record, while using an incremented value. Are you sure that those 'cid'-s match.

Comment: As you're just starting out, forget all that stuff about mysql_query and so on. Move to MySQLi and prepared statements etc.  The mysql_* stuff is all deprecated. (Or will be soon)

Comment: Ok I'll try to learn MySQLi, at this stage I'm just trying to not get overwhelmed with all these new concepts, as you can see I didn't even know about the die() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no error handling on your query calls:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which would tell you if there's any problems with the query execution. On a meta level, you're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so you'd better read up about that and fix the problem before you go any further with your code.

Comment: Aaaah, ok, didn't know. I added your code and it throws "No database selected", so a connection was probably not established, thanx. Going to see if I can get it to work, will update.

Comment: That'd be a missing `mysql_select_db()` call, in that case. If you hadn't connected at all, it'd say "no connection" or something similar. Never assume a query call succeeded. Even if the SQL statement itself is 100% valid, there's way too many other reasons for things to blow up to **NOT** check for failure.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "UPDATE course SET cname = '".$newname."' WHERE cid = '".$int."'";
```

is cID an integer ? in the update statement, looks to me like a string, try to echo every query and check the validity by executing it directly in your db

Answer (score 1):

where do you connect to the database??

use `mysql_connect(string hostname, string username, string password');` to connect to the database and then execute the query after selecting your database using `mysql_select_db`..

Comment: I establish the connection in includes, it was missing from my code which caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove the extra `;` on `$name="edit".$i;;`

Then, how do you post the values? I see no `<form>` attributes in your code, hence it cannot be posted.

Also, everything is in a for loop. `$newname=($_POST['text']);` is never being set.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of this:

```
if (isset($_POST[$name2]))
```

try this:

```
if ($name2!="")
```